# Prevent Image from Scaling Proportionally with HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html, canvas

I would like to be able to drawImage on a HTML5 canvas element where the image is resized to the canvas width but does not adjust the height.  Essentially I want it to crop the height to the canvas height rather than trying to scale the width AND height.

For example, if I drawImage on a canvas of 320 x 150.  I would like my image to scale down to the width of 320 and show the first 150 px of the height.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to calculate the image aspect ratio:

```
var f = image.height / image.width;
var newHeight = canvas.width * f;
```

And then draw using the recalculated height of image for destination:

```
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height, // source size
                     0, 0, canvas.width, newHeight);  // destination size
```

Canvas will do the clipping for you.

If you want to lets say center the destination vertical position you can do:

```
var destY = (canvas.height - image.height) / 2;

ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height,    // source size
                     0, destY, canvas.width, newHeight); // destination size
```

Comment: I'm almost there with your answer.  Curious, if I want the sourceY to be something other than 0, I would have expected to be able to
`ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 150, image.width, image.height, // source size
                     0, 0, canvas.width, newHeight);`

When I have a non-zero, I'm getting a blank canvas.  I'll keep at it, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I figured it out.  I had to adjust my destY instead.  Thanks for your help!